# Is there a specific word for multiple dot notations on an element?

Tags: javascript, dot-notation

What would you call using multiple dot notation's to a variable?

i.e: e.target.style.textDecoration

I've tried to Google search for an answer but not sure exactly how to word the question. Plus I would like to get familiar with asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: dot notation to nested object?

Comment: In javascript it's usually called "property lookup".

Comment: @Usaid I heard nothing about "property lookup".  I think you're wrong. It's called `chaining`.

Comment: @Alijvhr Just google "javascript property lookup". Chaining also seems correct. By using dot notation you are basically looking up the scope chain.

Comment: @Usaid Actually I did google it first because i didn't hear that. There is no such thing. But "property lookup" term is generally is referred as the algorithm a language internally uses to find an array index or property of an object!

Comment: @Alijvhr Yes, it's a general term. Also in my last comment, I made a mistake. It should be prototype chain not "scope" chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Chaining

It's called `Chaining`.

In JavaScript, chaining refers to the technique of calling multiple methods on an object one after the other, in a single line of code. The result of one method call is used as the object on which the next method call is made, and so on, creating a chain of method calls.

**Literally you are creating chains of calls!**

Chaining can make code more concise and easier to read, as it avoids the need to create temporary variables to store intermediate results.

[Here is a full article about it](https://blog.segunolalive.com/posts/understanding-method-chaining-in-javascript/)

For your Example:

```
e.target.style.textDecoration
```

Variable `e` is an object and `target` property of that is an object too. then `style` is a property of `e.target` and so on.

### Method Chaining

> Method Chaining is a programming strategy that simplifies and embellishes your code. It is a mechanism of calling a method on another method of the same object.

This can be done for methods, too. If the method return type be an `object`.

For instance:

```
documet.querySelector('.divClass').click();
```

Also there is A new operation you can check it out. It's called **Optional Chaining**
It checks parent not to be null. So no error will be issued if parent is null or non-object.
[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: By god I can't believe I didn't think of it being so simple! Thank you very much for the detailed response and answer!

Comment: Accept and vote up my answer if you found it helpful, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'm new to stackoverflow so I wasn't aware to accept it! I can't up-vote it as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @Markovian21 You have a good personality friend. thanks for the accepting. and modesty